# Retrieve timeout values from HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory using spring ReflectionUtils

Tags: java, spring, reflection, httpclient

I am using org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory in my code and I want to use Reflection (org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils) to retrieve some timeout values like ConnectTimeout from this object. I am not very clear on how to retrieve this field from this object.

I tried something like:  `ReflectionUtils.findField(httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.getClass(), "connectTimeout");`

But, the value is returned as null.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout values are part of the RequestConfig field of HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory. Following is the code to access the same.

```
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
factory.setConnectTimeout(1000);

Field requestConfigField = ReflectionUtils.findField(
   HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.class, "requestConfig", RequestConfig.class);
requestConfigField.setAccessible(true);
RequestConfig requestConfig = (RequestConfig) ReflectionUtils.getField(requestConfigField, factory);

System.out.println("Connect timeoout = " + requestConfig.getConnectTimeout());
```

Comment: Does object of type HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory not have any default values of these timeouts? I believe `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` DOES have a default timeout value of -1  because if you do  ```Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(simpleClientHttpRequestFactory.getClass(), "connectTimeout", int.class);
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory simpleClientHttpRequestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
  ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
        int v = (Integer)ReflectionUtils.getField(field, simpleClientHttpRequestFactory); v prints as -1 ```

Comment: (note that this is default value and we never had to set a timeout value on factory before retrieving it).
Whereas with httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory, if we dont set a timeout value first, we get RequestConfig as null. So is there a difference between SimpleFactory and httpComponents...Factory that the former has default timeouts whereas the latter does not?

Comment: If you do not invoke factory.setConnectTimeout() or similar methods, RequestConfig object will not be created. RequestConfig is part of Apache HTTP Components and not part of spring. The RequestConfig object is eventually passed to apache http client. If it is null, the default values as specified in RequestConfig class will be used. Check the source code of RequestConfig class for the default values.

Comment: this.staleConnectionCheckEnabled = false;
            this.redirectsEnabled = true;
            this.maxRedirects = 50;
            this.relativeRedirectsAllowed = true;
            this.authenticationEnabled = true;
            this.connectionRequestTimeout = -1;
            this.connectTimeout = -1;
            this.socketTimeout = -1;
            this.contentCompressionEnabled = true;


............................. The default connectTimeout is -1, which means that it waits for ever.

Comment: When you use SimpleHttpRequestFactory, the default http facilities (URLConnection) of JDK are used - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html